# How to catch the error message of bat file for deleting files in Inno Setup?

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am running a bat file, after the installation is done `CurStep = ssDone` to perform some deletion operation. if the files and folders are not found at the specified location. It is exiting silently. i want to show the message if the file does not exits or any other error occurs during deletion how can i catch the bat file errors in Inno Setup.

Batch file:

```
del "C:\archives\pages\*.txt"
```

Code:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
  log('Test'+ ExpandConstant('{tmp}\deletefiles.bat'))
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\deletefiles.bat'), '', '',
         SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode); 
    log('Done')
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should test the `ErrorCode` for a non zero exit code.

But Windows `del` command does not report errors with exit code unfortunately:
[Batch file and DEL errorlevel 0 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22953027/850848)

If you wanted to capture the output, see:
[How to get an output of an Exec'ed program in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1136770/850848)

---

And it's not good solution anyway to delete files using a batch file, if you can do the same directly in the Inno Setup Pascal Script code.

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    if not FindFirst('C:\path\*.txt', FindRec) then
    begin
      Log('Not found any files');
    end
      else
    begin
      try
        repeat
          if DeleteFile('C:\path\' + FindRec.Name) then
          begin
            Log(Format('Deleted %s', [FindRec.Name]));
          end
            else
          begin
            MsgBox(Format('Cannot delete %s', [FindRec.Name]), mbError, MB_OK);
          end;
        until not FindNext(FindRec);
      finally
        FindClose(FindRec);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

And if you do not need to do this in the `ssDone` step *(why would you?)*, just use the [`[InstallDelete]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installdeletesection).

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "C:\path\*.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you. InstallDelete would be the best option. Using it