# Is there a way to find out if a file deleted using system() got deleted?

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd, windows-10

I'm trying to make a program that deletes a list of files one by one, using `system()`.
The reason I'm using `system()` instead of `remove()` is because `remove()` doesn't support environment variables.

I've tried checking the return value, but my code seems to just always output that it's been deleted, even when it hasn't.

Code:

```
void fileLoop() {
    std::vector<std::string> fileList = { "\"%userprofile%\\test.txt\"" };
    while (!inter) {
        for (int count = 0; count <= 0; count++) {
            std::string moddedstring = "del /F " + fileList[count];
            DWORD checker = GetFileAttributes((LPCWSTR)fileList[count].c_str());
            if (checker == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
                goto next;
            }
            else {
                system(moddedstring.c_str());
                MessageBoxW(NULL, L"File found, successfully deleted", L"File Deleted", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
            }
            next:
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

I thought there is some easy way to find this out. I haven't found a way like that yet.

I will be adding more paths later.

**Update:**

I've tried using `OpenProcessToken()` with `ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUserW()` to add ENVs

But it complains that my buffer is of type `LPCSTR*` **even** when I set it to `LPCSTR`

Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953027/batch-file-and-del-errorlevel-0-issue - only way with `del` is to either parse its output and look for an error message (you could use e.g. `_popen` or similar instead of `system`), or use something like `GetFileAttributes` (or `lstat`) to see if the file exists.

Comment: PS while `del` doesn't return a meaningful status, you still probably want to get that `echo $?` out of there since it could just further confuse return codes.

Comment: "The reason I'm using `system()` instead of `remove()` is because `remove()` doesn't support environment variables." - Then why don't you construct your file name by [looking up the environment variables yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/631664/364696)?

Comment: ^^^ you can use [`ExpandEnvironmentStringsW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsw) (or `*A`)

Comment: @JasonC: Thanks, I forgot they made it even easier on Windows. :-) I suppose for this specific case, `GetUserProfileDirectory` (`*W` or `*A` variant) or one of [the other `userenv.h` functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/) would also apply.

Comment: @JasonC I tried `GetFileAttributes` but when the file was found it didn't throw my Msgbox.
Any idea why?

Comment: To be clear, the reason I suggest this is that calling out via `system` limits your ability to detect and respond to errors; the exit code is not super-informative, relative to return codes, `errno`, `GetLastError()`, etc.

Comment: you'd have to show what you did. could be a good new question.

Comment: Don't use `system`, it is a gaping hole into your program and allows remote code execution.

Comment: @ShadowRanger My ENV that I want to use isn't the environment variable of the path, 
it's the ENV of `%USERPROFILE%`. If you know how to do that then please show me.

Comment: @JasonC I have removed the `echo $?` out of my main program

Comment: @TheException: `%USERPROFILE%` is just how you say "look up `USERPROFILE` from the environment and replace the placeholder with it". The `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` function JasonC mentioned can do the same work; [the docs have examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/getting-system-information).

Comment: @TheException the *better* way to get the user's profile path is to use `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_PROFILE)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile)`. That said, use `DeleteFile()` instead of `system("del")`. And, `(LPCWSTR)fileList[count].c_str()` will not work like you think, drop the typecast and use `GetFileAttributesA()` instead. Or, simply don't bother checking attributes at all, call `DeleteFile()` unconditionally and let it tell you if it succeeded or failed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `SHGetFolderPath()` and `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` have **a lot** more params than that.

Comment: @TheException I'm aware of that, I was not showing you actual code snippets, simply mentioning the function names and the appropriate folder IDs to use with them.

Comment: There is no reason for not using [file APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/) and the number of parameters should not be a disadvantage. Or at least, as @JasonC suggested, use [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/getting-system-information) which works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *better* way to get the user's profile path is to simply ask the OS directly, via `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_PROFILE)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile)`.

Also, you should use `DeleteFileA()` instead of `system("del")`.  There is no need to spawn an external console process when you can do the deletion directly.  Also, because you are interested in error checking, which is much easier if you use the Win32 API directly.

Also, `(LPCWSTR)fileList[count].c_str()` *will not* work like you think. You can't convert a `const char*` to a `const wchar_t*` using a simple typecast. Drop the typecast and use `GetFileAttributesA()` instead.

Or, simply don't bother checking attributes at all. You can call `DeleteFileA()` unconditionally and let it tell you if it actually succeeded or failed.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
#include <shlobj.h>

std::string getUserProfilePath() {
    CHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (FAILED(SHGetFolderPathA(NULL, CSIDL_PROFILE, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, szPath))) {
        // error handling...
        throw ...;
    }
    int len = lstrlenA(szPath);
    szPath[len] = '\\';
    return std::string(szPath, len + 1);

    /*
    PWSTR pszPath;
    if (FAILED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &pszPath))) {
        // error handling...
        throw ...;
    }
    int wlen = lstrlenW(pszPath);
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(0, 0, pszPath, wlen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (len == 0) {
        // error handling...
        throw ...;
    }
    std::vector<CHAR> buffer(len + 1);
    len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pszPath, wlen, buffer.data(), len, NULL, NULL);
    if (len == 0) {
        // error handling...
        throw ...;
    }
    buffer[len] = '\\';
    CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);
    return std::wstring(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    */
}

void fileLoop() {
    std::vector<std::string> fileList = { getUserProfilePath() + "test.txt" };
    while (!inter) {
        for (size_t count = 0; count < fileList.size(); ++count) {
            if (DeleteFileA(fileList[count].c_str())) {
                MessageBoxW(NULL, L"File found, successfully deleted", L"File Deleted", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
            } else {
                // error handling...
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, using Unicode strings instead (which you really should use when interacting with the filesystem):

```
#include <shlobj.h>

std::wstring getUserProfilePath() {
    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (FAILED(SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_PROFILE, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, szPath))) {
        // error handling...
        throw ...;
    }
    int len = lstrlenW(szPath);
    szPath[len] = '\\';
    return std::wstring(szPath, len + 1);

    /*
    PWSTR pszPath;
    if (FAILED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &pszPath))) {
        // error handling...
        throw ...;
    }
    int len = lstrlenW(pszPath);
    std::wstring sPath(len + 1, '\0');
    std::copy(pszPath, pszPath + len, sPath.begin());
    sPath[len] = '\\';
    CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);
    return sPath;
    */
}

void fileLoop() {
    std::vector<std::wstring> fileList = { getUserProfilePath() + L"test.txt" };
    while (!inter) {
        for (size_t count = 0; count < fileList.size(); ++count) {
            if (DeleteFileW(fileList[count].c_str())) {
                MessageBoxW(NULL, L"File found, successfully deleted", L"File Deleted", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
            } else {
                // error handling...
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Even better, if you are using C++17 or later, consider using the `<filesystem>` library instead:

```
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <filesystem>

using fs = std::filesystem;

fs::path getUserProfilePath() {
    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (FAILED(SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_PROFILE, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, szPath))) {
        // error handling...
        throw ...;
    }
    return szPath;

    /*
    PWSTR pszPath;
    if (FAILED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &pszPath))) {
        // error handling...
        throw ...;
    }
    fs::path pth(pszPath);
    CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);
    return pth;
    */
}

void fileLoop() {
    std::vector<fs::path> fileList = { getUserProfilePath() / L"test.txt" };
    while (!inter) {
        for (auto &pth : fileList) {
            std::error_code ec;
            if (fs::remove(pth, ec)) {
                MessageBoxW(NULL, L"File found, successfully deleted", L"File Deleted", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
            } else {
                // error handling...
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `remove()` okay to use?
I also used `f.good()` to check if the file exists.
By using that and `SHGetFolderPath` it worked!

Comment: "*Is `remove()` okay to use?*" - Why wouldn't it be okay? On Windows, it is just going to call `DeleteFile()` internally for you. So cut out the middle-man. "*I also used `f.good()` to check if the file exists*" - there is no `f` in the code shown. But, in any case, you should not check if a file exists before creating/deleting it. That is a [TOCTOU race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). Let the file system handle that for you. Simply create/delete the file unconditionally and let it fail if the file (already|does not) exist(s), respectively.