# Exist, Rmdir and %errorlevel% in batch Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel, rmdir

I don't think that my question is duplicate to [batch: Exit code for "rd" is 0 on error as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137702/batch-exit-code-for-rd-is-0-on-error-as-well) because I've tried everything from that answer and it didn't help (as you can see on screenshots below).

Let's say I want to delete directory with files in it. But I don't want script to continue executing in case of an error. So I tried to:

```
ECHO 3. Deleting Client index folder which will be rebuilt if it actually exist...
rmdir /S /Q "XXX"
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO Failed to delete client index folder... & GOTO :End
```

But %ERRORLEVEL% variable was always equal 0.
[image]

Then I found similar questions on Stackoverflow and changed script to this:

```
ECHO 3. Deleting Client index folder which will be rebuilt if it actually exist...
rmdir /S /Q "XXX" && echo OK || echo ERROR
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO Failed to delete client index folder... & GOTO :End
```

And it worked well!
[image]

But the problem is that I want script to continue working if folder doesn't exist (i.e. was already deleted). With that implementation it wasn't working.
[image]

So I changed script like this:

```
ECHO 3. Deleting Client index folder which will be rebuilt if it actually exist...
if exist "XXX" (rmdir /S /Q "%4_%5" && echo OK || echo ERROR)
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO Failed to delete client index folder... & GOTO :End
```

Aaaaaaaand it stopped setting up %ErrorLevel% variable again in case of file lock...
[image]

I've tried to remove brackets after "exist" condition. Tried to change "if exist" to "2>nul", but none of these options work as I need. Any suggestions on how I should fix it?

Comment: Note that in your situation, [rychu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562902/886887) provides a much easier workaround.  `if exist xxx rd /s /q xxx` then `if exist xxx echo Oops` then `if exist xxx goto :End` concise and  easy to understand.

Comment: Note also that there is an issue in Windows that sometimes causes the first `rd` to fail at random.  You can resolve this by repeating the first line, i.e., `if exist xxx rd /s /q xxx` followed by `if exist xxx rd /s /q xxx` and then check for an error.  Doing it twice looks redundant, but it *will* make it more reliable.

Comment: Dude you are my savior. Yeap, first option with trying to delete directory and "if exist" check afterwards seems nice and clean! Thank you!

Comment: First, rd (rmdir) works partially for errno 32 (file in being used by another process) that is works only if /s flag is not used. Second, it does not work at all for errno 5 (access denied) if this "access denied" comes from some file inside the target directory. See comments under https://stackoverflow.com/a/11137825/4807875.