# Access denied in batch file sets error level to 0

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that moves a file.  I'm testing it and have got an access denied error which I can fix easily, however I've noticed that the errorlevel for this issue is still 0.

I would expect the value to be higher than that.  Any ideas?

```
move /Y "C:\TestNoPersmissions" "E:\somedestination"
echo %errorlevel%
if errorlevel 1 goto Failure
if errorlevel 0 goto Success

:Failure
eventcreate /t error /id 100 /so TestMove /l application /d "Move product XML failure" 
echo Error!

:Success
echo "Success"
pause
```

Comment: presumably OT, but your `:Failure` response should not fall through to your `:Success` one. Oh, also: you simply expect the wrong thing from `if errorlevel`, which is a very counterintuitive language 'feature'.

Comment: You need to put `goto :EOF` or `exit /B` before `:Failure` and `:Success`; otherwise execution falls into those routines unintentionally... Do you have your `move` and `echo` commands in a loop or any other parenthesised block of code?

Comment: @underscore_d, this is not the problem here, because the OP did the `if ErrorLevel` checks in descending order.

Comment: Show the exact output so people know what you mean by "ive noticed that the errorlevel for this issue is still", i.e. whether it *really* is or you just mistakenly infer that it is.

Comment: I'd assume that `If ErrorLevel` is returning the success of the `Echo` command. _Remove the `echo %errorlevel%` line and try it again._

Comment: @Compo, didn't we have a thread going on DosTips about which commands reset the errorlevel?  Seems odd that `echo` would be one of them.

Comment: removing the echo did not make any difference

Comment: And the errorlevel is definatley 0.  I get an access denied to support the fact that the account does not have pernissions. If i update the code and set the source folder to a path that doesnt exist i get an errorlevel 1.

Comment: possible dupe of ["rd" exits with errorlevel set to 0 on error when deletion fails, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137702/batch-exit-code-for-rd-is-0-on-error-as-well/29562902)